# Text Engine Option not avaiable in preferences of photoshop CS 6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I m trying to write Arabic text in adobe photoshop CS6. I checked many tutorials to do this job but I m stuck because in every tut I found this:

"To type Arabic or Hebrew in Photoshop, you need to enable the Middle Eastern text engine. You can do this by going to Preferences > Type.
The process is Very well described in this video.
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17789/how-do-i-type-arabic-text-in-photoshop/20001#20001

I can type the Arabic language from keyboard but the characters are disjoint. When I tried to paste the joined-character Arabic text from translate.google.com, the characters become disjoint immediately after pasting.

**I can not see any text engine option when I open my preferences of adobe photoshop cs6.** 
I have been bumping my head to solve this issue for 2 hours but all in vein.
[image: The window looks like the figure attached.]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's there in my CS6 extended. Do you have the extended version? Is it a legal version?

Comment: What should I do now to get this thing fixed? 
Download and install the whole ME version or is there any plug-in that can fix this issue

Comment: I had to check... and I edited my previous comment.

Comment: No, it is downloaded from torrent and cracked by library "ambit.dll" of extended version.

Answer (score 1):

You should open

> Type -> Language Option... -> ...and change language to Arabic.

After you have set *Left-to-Right Character Direction* on *Language Option*,  everything you want to write should be ok. And you will write normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

you have missing graphic drivers from your system because in your attached screenshot its also not displaying the 3D tab below type tab(Edit> Preference> type)

you first install all your graphic drivers and I am sure this will solve your problem

Comment: My graphics driver is perfectly installed. All other apps are working properly. The driver revision date is later than Adobe CS6 release date.
Now I have installed Adobe CC and get my objectives done.

Answer (score 0):

guys
i was have same problem and my photoshop in  preferences > Type was not any options for text engine option...
but 
in my photoshop i run  "apply middle east composser" in  edit > Apply middle east compossor
and now i can wrote persian and arabic...
I hope this answer be useful...
sorry for my english ...

Answer (score 0):

After setting:

```
Preferences > Type > World-Ready Layout
```

this is only applied to **Newly Created Documents**. If you have any previously created documents, you may consider recreating those.

You should also enable:

```
Type > Language Options > Middle Eastern Features
```